# Eorror when try recorder RTSP stream FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to record a stream from my camera using `ffmpeg` but an error is returned.

I am using the command:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://ip_camp:port/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp? -acodec copy -vcodec copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 C:\backup-cam\test.mp4`.

The error returned:

> [rtsp @ 0000026490509980] method DESCRIBE failed: 451 ERROR
>       rtsp://ip_cam:port/user=admin: Server returned 4XX Client Error, but not one of 40{0,1,3,4}
>       'password' is not recognized as an internal command
>       or external, an operable program or a batch file.
>       'channel' is not recognized as an internal command
>       or external, an operable program or a batch file.
>       'stream' is not recognized as an internal command
>       or external, an operable program or a batch file.

Comment: Wrap entire input in quotes.

Comment: its works, tanks!!